# Weird invalid character error

Tags: errors, characters

I get this weird error with this code and I have no idea why:

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.45 ^^@
^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
```

I already tried removing the aux. file, but that did not help. I can't find a character that might cause this error.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=1.5cm,includefoot]{geometry} % defines margin of all pages of the thesis
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % sets the line spacing to one and a half 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} % for multiple figures in one figure tab
\listfiles
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{titlesec} %for subsubsub sections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\usepackage{amsmath} % needed for mathematical symbols like °C
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{bm} %enables to make math bolf faced
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}   

 \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Add caption}
        \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
        \toprule
        Sample & Humidity & Solvent & Concentration & Distance & Feedrate & Voltage & Volume & Molecular Weight & Date  & comments \\
        \midrule
              &       &       & [wt \%] & [cm]  & [$\mu$l/min] & [kv]  & [ml]  &       &       &  \\
        1     & 40    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 20    & 11    & 6     & 26.5  &       & 530,000 & 16.10.2015 &  \\
        2     & 40    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 20    & 14    & 10    & 26.5  &       & 530,000 & 16.10.2015 &  \\
        3     & 40    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 20    & 20    & 10    & 26.5  &       & 530,000 & 16.10.2015 &  \\
        4     & 40    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 20    & 23    & 80    & 25    &       & 530,000 & 16.10.2015 &  \\
        5     & 40    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 20    & 12    & 3     & 18    &       & 530,000 & 22.10.2015 &  \\
        6     & 50    & 7 DMF : 3 Acetone & 17    & 10    & 3     & 20    &       & 530,000 & 23.10.2015 & PVDF turned yellow/ degraded, maybe temperature was too high \\
        7     & 50    & 7 DMF : 3 Acetone & 17    & 10    & 3     & 21    &       & 530,000 & 23.10.2015 & PVDF turned yellow/ degraded, maybe temperature was too high \\
        8     & 50    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 15    & 10    & 3     & s     &       & 530,000 & 27.10.2015 &  \\
        9     & 49    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 20    & 13    & 6     & 24    &       & 530,000 & 29.10.2015 &  \\
        10    & 49    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 20    & 15    & 6     & 24    &       & 530,000 & 29.10.2015 &  \\
        11    & 55    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 20    & 18    & 6     & 20    &       & 530,000 & 30.10.2015 &  \\
        12    & 55    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 20    & 18    & 6     & 25    &       & 530,000 & 30.10.2015 &  \\
        13    & 50    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 15    & 18    & 8     & 25    & 1     & 530,000 & 4.11.2015 &  \\
        14    & 50    & 2 DMAC :3 Acetone & 15    & 15    & 8     & 25    & 0.5   & 530,000 & 4.11.2015 &  \\
        15    & 50    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 15    & 8     & 25    & 0.5   & 530,000 & 5.11.2015 &  \\
        16    & 50    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 15    & 8     & 15    & 0.5   & 530,000 & 5.11.2015 &  \\
        17    & 50    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 10    & 8     & 13    & 0.5   & 530,000 & 5.11.2015 & voltage adjusted till i got a stable Taylor's cone \\
        18    & 50    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 18    & 8     & 16    & 1     & 530,000 & 5.11.2015 & voltage adjusted till i got a stable Taylor's cone \\
        19    & 55    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 15    & 8     & 15    & 0.5   & 530,000 & 10.11.2015 &  \\
        20    & 53    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 16    & 8     & 15    & 0.5   & 530,000 & 10.11.2015 &  \\
        21    & 51    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 16    & 8     & 14    & 0.5   & 530,000 & 10.11.2015 &  \\
        22    & 46    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 20    & 8     & 15    &       & 530,000 & 12.11.2015 & thick needle \\
        23    & 46    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 17    & 8     & 13    &       & 530,000 & 12.11.2015 & thick needle \\
        24    & 46    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 16    & 8     & 12.4  &       & 530,000 & 12.11.2015 & thick needle \\
        25    & 46    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 17    & 8     & 13.1  &       & 530,000 & 12.11.2015 &  \\
        26    & 46    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 16    & 8     & 12.6  &       & 530,000 & 12.11.2015 &  \\
        27    & 46    & 3 DMAC :7 Acetone & 15    & 15    & 8     &      &       & 530,000 & 12.11.2015 &  \\

        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me (and produces a poorly cropped table). What distribution of `TeX` are you using?

Comment: @jlv It may compile fine because all those weird characters are “cleaned” or normalized by this site when OP copied code to the question.

Comment: I just copied the table from here back to texmaker and it works now! So strange. Thanks guys!

Comment: `^^@` is tex syntax for byte 0 ie as ASCII NULL character which is usually a sign of filesystem corruption somewhere.,

Comment: Yep, @DavidCarlisle is right. Could be a glitch, but I would backup *now* (well, you should have always a good backup, but well...).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue cannot be reproduced and is probably caused by a misfeature of the OP's editor